# HTML/CSS: Avoid black background under image while loading

Tags: css, background-color

Here is my CSS:

```
body {
color: #ffffff;
background-color: #8f8f8f;

background: url(images/noise_int.png) repeat center; /* fallback */
...
background: radial-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, .3) 10%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .8) 90%), url(images/noise_int.png) repeat center, #8f8f8f; /* W3C */
height: auto;
background-size: auto; 
}
```

(I did strip out the excess background lines for all the browsers.) Now I believe that the background color is first set to the gray hue.  Then it is told to be a transparent gradient, on top on an image, on top of the gray hue.  I thought this would mean that while the image was loading below it there would be the gray hue, however this is not the case.  While the image is loading below it is black.  This happens when the image is progressive and interlaced.  Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Comment: Consider adding a jsFiddle so I can see what the problem is. I'd be glad to help.

Comment: I think you have over complicated it personally, if you want a grey hue while it is loading, then set that as the background color, then set the image on the next line. Its called cascading style sheet for a reason, and I can't see why a simple option like that won't be effective? Also how bigger image file is this you need to worry about what appears when its loading, to me that seams like an issue in its self?

Comment: Tim, so like as you see in my question where I set 'background-color: #8f8f8f;' and then where I set the background image later? Is that what you think I should do?  Is not that it's a big file its that the user will see a white flash for a second before the image loads. (It's interlaced to help with loading) @Mitchell see this: http://jsfiddle.net/2ZT72/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
background: #000000 url(images/noise_int.png) repeat center;
```